# How to maintain state after a page refresh in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I have code that sets state for a select box chosen on the previous page:

```
this.setState({selectedOption: 5});
```

Is there any way to have `this.state.selectedOption` populated with 5 after a page refresh?

Are there callbacks that I can use to save this in localStorage and then do one large `setState` or is there a standard way of doing something like this?

Comment: http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/

Answer (score 81):

So my solution was to also set `localStorage` when setting my state and then get the value from `localStorage` again inside of the `getInitialState` callback like so:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var selectedOption = localStorage.getItem( 'SelectedOption' ) || 1;

    return {
        selectedOption: selectedOption
    };
},

setSelectedOption: function( option ) {
    localStorage.setItem( 'SelectedOption', option );
    this.setState( { selectedOption: option } );
}
```

I'm not sure if this can be considered an [Anti-Pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) but it works unless there is a better solution.

Comment: The only part of this that I would consider to be a bit of an "anti-pattern" is that your component is persisting it's own state inside of localStorage. If this component was used multiple times, then you would have to deal with key collisions. Imo, information that is this important (needs to be persisted to localStorage) should probably be moved up to a higher state or data layer within the applications architecture... but this is the easiest way to get the job done until the details are worked out

Comment: @CoryDanielson what should be the recommended way then?

Comment: If you wanted to use localStorage to save the state in a way that would be safe across multiple instances of the same component, you could give each component a unique ID and then use that ID as the key in localStorage - like ``${this.props.id}.SelectedOption``

Comment: If the input is part of a form (or group of related inputs), you could save all of the inputs/values to a single object, and then JSON.stringify the object and store the string in localStorage

Comment: If you replace `localStorage` with [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) you get separate states for each tab, avoiding collisions across tabs

Answer (score 28):

We have an application that allows the user to set "parameters" in the page. What we do is set those params on the URL, using React Router (in conjunction with History) and a library that URI-encodes JavaScript objects into a format that can be used as your query string.

When the user selects an option, we can push the value of that onto the current route with:

```
history.push({pathname: 'path/', search: '?' + Qs.stringify(params)});
```

`pathname` can be the current path. In your case `params` would look something like:

```
{
  selectedOption: 5
}
```

Then at the top level of the React tree, React Router will update the `props` of that component with a prop of `location.search` which is the encoded value we set earlier, so there will be something in `componentWillReceiveProps` like:

```
params = Qs.parse(nextProps.location.search.substring(1));
this.setState({selectedOption: params.selectedOption});
```

Then that component and its children will re-render with the updated setting. As the information is on the URL it can be bookmarked (or emailed around - this was our use case) and a refresh will leave the app in the same state.
This has been working really well for our application.

React Router: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

History: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history

The query string library: https://github.com/ljharb/qs

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, rather than saving to local storage, which isn't always possible and slows the app down. Am going to try and apply this, thank you.

Comment: Can this work for large arrays?

Comment: Is this still recommended when the desired states are on different pages and have nothing to do with any other page than their own?

Comment: That sounds like a very different scenario @Swirle13 - you might want to ask a new question for that one.

Answer (score 23):

You can "persist" the state using local storage as Omar Suggest, but it should be done once the state has been set. For that you need to pass a callback to the `setState` function and you need to serialize and deserialize the objects put into local storage.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    allProjects: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allProjects')) || []
  }
}


addProject = (newProject) => {
  ...

  this.setState({
    allProjects: this.state.allProjects.concat(newProject)
  },() => {
    localStorage.setItem('allProjects', JSON.stringify(this.state.allProjects))
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same in functional component: like this
  
setScenario({ ...scenario, Tags: tags] }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('scenarioTags', JSON.stringify( tags]))
  });
this one doesnt work currently

Answer (score 12):

With Hooks and sessionStorage:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("count")));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("count", count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Replace sessionStorage with localStorage if that is what you still prefer.

Comment: Why two useEffect?

Comment: Hi @Quimbo, who can remember… Because the (code inside the) first one should run on every render, including a page refresh, while the second one should only run when `count` is changed

Answer (score 8):

I consider state to be for view only information and data that should persist beyond the view state is better stored as props.  URL params are useful when you want to be able to link to a page or share the URL deep in to the app but otherwise clutter the address bar.

Take a look at Redux-Persist (if you're using redux) https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 3):

With hooks:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedSelectedOption = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedOption') || '1')
    setSelectedOption(storedSelectedOption)
  }, [])

  const handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setSelectedOption(parseInt(e.target.value))
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedOption', e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <select onChange={handleOnChange}>
      <option value="5" selected={selectedOption === 5}>Five</option>
      <option value="3" selected={selectedOption === 3}>Three</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

Apparently this also works:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<number>(() => {
    return parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedOption') || '1')
  })

  const handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setSelectedOption(parseInt(e.target.value))
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedOption', e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <select onChange={handleOnChange}>
      <option value="5" selected={selectedOption === 5}>Five</option>
      <option value="3" selected={selectedOption === 3}>Three</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

In modern browsers:

```
return (
  <select onChange={handleOnChange} value={selectedOption}>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
)
```

For input *something* like this should work:

(In reply to question in comment from @TanviAgarwal)

```
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { name, value, onChange } = props

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(() => {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(name) || value || ''
  })

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    onChange && onChange(e)
    setInputValue(e.target.value)
    sessionStorage.setItem(name, e.target.value)
  }

  return <input ref={ref} {...props} value={inputValue} onChange={handleOnChange} />
})
```

(With typescript it's a bit more complicated, but not horribly so)

This will store the value "forever", so you have to somehow handle resetting the form.

Comment: For an array of objects, there are input fields with edit options how can this be made possible? I am trying your code but after refresh the value it getting away. @tofsjonas

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you provide a code example?

Comment: const cols = [
        {
            title: "Name",
            field: "name",
        },
        {
            title: "Class",
            field: "class",
        }
    ];
const table= [ {name:'Tanvi', class:'high-school' } ];  these are the two arrays I am using.  I am trying to create a list with input fields which are editable but after refresh data is getting away

Comment: {cols.map((e, index) => <div><ListItem button><ListItemText primary={e.title} />
<div><ListItemSecondaryAction><Input placeholder="Enter"                                  variant="outlined"  size='small'   onChange={handleAdd} value={editAssessment}                                  /><Button outlined="true" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => saveEdit(e.field)}> Save</Button></ListItemSecondaryAction>
                            </div>
                        </ListItem>)}

Comment: @TanviAgarwal I made an edit, the code in the comments are not that readable..

Comment: thank you for sharing this, I will try in my code. Actually I could not share code properly in comments due to word limit. Can you suggest other medium to reach out to share complete code?

Answer (score 2):

Load **state** from localStorage if exist:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);           
    this.state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
        : initialState
```

override `this.setState` to automatically save **state** after each update :

```
const orginial = this.setState;     
this.setState = function() {
    let arguments0 = arguments[0];
    let arguments1 = () => (arguments[1], localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(this.state)));
    orginial.bind(this)(arguments0, arguments1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late but the actual code for react-create-app for react > 16 ver. After each change state is saved in sessionStorage (not localStorage) and is encrypted via crypto-js. On refresh (when user demands refresh of the page by clicking refresh button) state is loaded from the storage. I also recommend not to use sourceMaps in the build to avoid the readability of the key phrases.

my `index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import './index.css';
import App from './containers/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("someRandomText_encryptionPhase");
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("someRandomIV");
const persistedState = loadFromSessionStorage();

let store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

function loadFromSessionStorage() {
    try {
        const serializedState = sessionStorage.getItem('state');
        if (serializedState === null) {
            return undefined;
        }
        const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(serializedState, key, {iv: iv}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        return JSON.parse(decrypted);
    } catch {
        return undefined;
    }
}

function saveToSessionStorage(state) {
        try {
            const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
            const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(serializedState, key, {iv: iv});
            sessionStorage.setItem('state', encrypted)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App/>
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

store.subscribe(() => saveToSessionStorage(store.getState()));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: what is the point of encrypting since the key has to be on the frontend therefore can be found with inspector tools in the browser?

Comment: @MehdiSaffar You encrypt the data not the key. Someone with the key will get the encrypted data but that means nothing unless you also have the secretKey to decrypt the data