# Going back to previous page using back button clears all filters

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need help in a Reactjs app built with flux architecture. I have few filters on my current page but When I go to another page come back using browser's back button I lose all the filters.  I had done some research and found using HTML5 local storage is one of the approach to solve it. I dont how to approach it. Could anyone please help me fix this problem Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js can give you an idea how to do it with local storage.

Comment: Do you mean navigating to a different route within the single page app? Or are you talking about a full page refresh?

Comment: Hi Joe, I mean to a different route.