# ReactJS how to persist state in cookies

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Below is sample example for counter but i have to maintain the state after page is refree.For example i will increment the counter to 10 and next time when my page refreshes the page should start with 10 instead of 1.
Can anyhow guide me regarding this.

Comment: You're missing the code example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain state after a page refresh in React.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use cookies [JS-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) is really handy. Setting and retrieving cookie is really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But is there any other way to maintain state other than local storage and session storage

Comment: Can we maintain state in flux pattern phenomenon

Comment: Sorry but i did not get you.. are u talking about storage or flux?

Comment: I was talking about storage

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage for that.

In your action handler do:

```
let counter = window.localStorage.getItem("counter");
window.localStorage.setItem("counter ", ++counter);
```

Then in your componentDidMount do:

```
let counter = window.localStorage.getItem("counter");
this.setState("counter", counter);
```

Comment: Will localStorage be appropriate if application is universal and uses server-side rendering?

Comment: No. But I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: I am bit new to react...can flux help in maintaining the state