# retaining the state after I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to learn react myself.
- when I hit favorites button which is the heart symbol changes the color.
- but when I refresh the page it disappears.
- so I researched and found the below link
  [How to maintain state after a page refresh in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js)
- after implementing now I am able to see the local storage in the developer tools application tab.
- but after I refresh still the color is not retained.
- when I debugged I found in getInitialState nothing is printing will that be problem
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my relevant code snippet and sandbox below.
- all my code is in RecipeReviewCard.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/xrp56z04yq

```or-tag-here
  getInitialState = () => {
    var addFavirote = localStorage.getItem("AddFavirote") || 1;
    console.log("getInitialState--->", addFavirote);

    return {
      addFavirote: addFavirote
    };

    //this.setState(state => ({ belowExpanded: !state.belowExpanded }));
  };


<FavoriteIcon
              style={{ display: this.state.addFavirote ? "none" : "" }}
              onClick={e => {
                console.log("favoriteEvent---.", e);
                console.log(
                  "this.state.addFavirote---.",
                  this.state.addFavirote
                );

                localStorage.setItem("AddFavirote", !this.state.addFavirote);
                this.setState({ addFavirote: !this.state.addFavirote });

                console.log(
                  "!this.state.addFavirote---.",
                  !this.state.addFavirote
                );

                this.props.onAddBenchmark(this.props);
              }}
            />
```

Comment: It is difficult to determine what `addFavorite` could be containing. From the post you linked, you need to `JSON.stringify(addFavorite)` and `parse` back to hydrate `state`

Comment: @Orar sorry I forgot to paste my sandbox link...can you update here its so confusing :(  https://codesandbox.io/s/xrp56z04yq

Comment: @Orar can you tell me how to find hydra state

Comment: Sorry i didnt mean hydrate as a function. Just English. I meant It is difficult to determine what `addFavorite` could be containing. From the post you linked, you need to `JSON.stringify(addFavorite)` and `JSON.parse` back to set state. I looked at the codesandbox but couldn't find which component is the snippet is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [LocalStorage syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#Syntax) documentation, you will need to serialize `addFavorite` to string to set to local storage. On `componentDidMount` when value is retrieved from localStorage, you can parse it back to the original content in `getInitialState`.

For example, you could

```
localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(!this.state.addFavorite)) //ie "true" || "false"
```

and get it back as

```
getInitialState = () => {
  let fav = localStorage.getItem('AddFavorite');
  let addFavorite = JSON.parse(fav || "true");
  this.setState({ addFavorite });
}
```

PS: I recommend setting localStorage in `componentWillUnmount` if it wouldnt break things. Setting local storage and JSON serialization will affect performance.

Comment: @Omar thanks for your reply...my code is in RecipeReviewCard.js it starts at line number 63...it would be great if you update here its so confusing :(  https://codesandbox.io/s/xrp56z04yq