# Choose item from Navbar - item stays highlited

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I have simple Navbar like this:

```
 <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`}>
        Blah
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/SomePage`}>
        SomePage
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
```

When I put cursor on NavItem its highlited but I would like it to be highlighted after I click on it, to inform me where on page I am.
So: to sumuarize, anyone knows how to keep selected navitem highlighted?

Comment: You will have to store the last clicked nav in your state. In your render, give a different className to the nave that has the same `id` as the selected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think firstly you need to be using **unique event key** for each `NavItem`.

**Nav** has a prop `activeKey` and a handler `onSelect`, make use of this to set the **activekey** on Nav.

```
<Nav activeKey={(this.state.activeKey)} 
onSelect={e => {e.preventDefault(); this.handleSelect(e);}>
```

After this, you will get an `active` prop on the clicked active item, so now its the time for some **CSS pseudo selector**.

```
.NavItem:active{
  background-color: green; //some color of your choice//
}
```

Comment: I did sth similar: 
 ```<Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={(this.state.activeKey)} onSelect={e => {this.handleSelect(e)}}>```
but I does not keep highlight

Comment: No, no the way I want. It highlights when I put cursor on it but its not highlighter afterwards.

Comment: I think it may not help. I see the problem in console. If I click on the item, page is refreshed and activeKey dissapears.

Comment: you should be doing e.preventDefault() in the handler

Comment: Still doesnt work, I will try to figure out whats going on...
Right now I got: 
TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: managed to fix it, using localstroage: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js
Thanks for your help : )