# Persist state with React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the useContext and useReducer hooks in my app to have a global state mimic Redux in my app. The problem I have is that I would like to persist the state (or at least some things) when the user refreshes the website. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain state after a page refresh in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through local storage, you can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage