# Reload current page in React without losing state

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to reload the same page in react. I try with history.push and Redirect from 'react-router-dom' but dosnt work. With window.location i loose the state.

Comment: For what reason are you trying to reload the page outside of the normal lifecycle updates? I.e., any non-null setState() call with cause a render - why not work within this known mechanism?

Comment: maybe you can find more about this here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to maintain state after a page refresh in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could save your state in localStorage and hydrate on page reload.

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-take-advantage-of-local-storage-in-your-react-projects-a895f2b2d3f2