# Does react state change when i refresh a page

Tags: reactjs

```js
`class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.sideBarToggleHandler = this.sideBarToggleHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      sideBarOpen: true,
      backDropOpen: false,
      isPrim: true,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentdidmount')
  }

  sideBarToggleHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { sideBarOpen: !prevState.sideBarOpen }
    })

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { backDropOpen: !prevState.backDropOpen }
    })
  }

  changeTheme = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { isPrim: !prevState.isPrim }
    })
  }

  render() {
    let backDrop;

    if (this.state.backDropOpen) {
      backDrop = <SideDrop />
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <SimpleBar style={{ height: '100vh' }}>

          <ThemeSwitcher changeTheme={this.changeTheme} />

          <ToggleBar sideBarToggleHandler={this.sideBarToggleHandler} />

          {backDrop}

          <SideBar sideBarOpen={this.state.sideBarOpen} />

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
            <Route exact path='/about' render={() => <AboutPage isPrim={this.state.isPrim} />} />
            <Route exact path='/resume' render={() => <ResumePage isPrim={this.state.isPrim} />} />
            <Route exact path='/portfolio' component={PortfolioPage} />
            <Route exact path='/blog' component={BlogPage} />
            <Route exact path='/contact' component={ContactPage} />
          </Switch>
        </SimpleBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}`
```

I want to change the theme of my website based on a state object but when the theme is changed for the first time and i navigate to another page component it changes back to the original theme, i've added my app component code it uses react router for pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state persists only in the front end, meaning that every time you refresh the page a new state is created. You can avoid loosing your state between pages by using [React router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), which handles your multi page without actually refreshing the site.
You could also use local storage to store your state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28314706,
 altho I would do both

Comment: i am actually using react router but when i navigate through the pages the app component re-renders so how do i prevent that

Comment: Maybe you could post some code, so I can take a look at it

Comment: The code that you posted appears correct, perhaps the problem isn't here. How are you switching between the pages?

Comment: i'm switching between pages through the side-bar using a tags

Comment: ` <ul className='side-bar-elements'>
                <li>
                    <span className="lnr lnr-home"></span>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
              `

Comment: That is the problem. When changin pages you want router to handle the change, so you dont fetch everything again. Instead of <a> tags, use Link tags from Router https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is not possible to save the state values on refreshing, you can save it in local storage. and if you use one of routing libraries page should not refresh.

Comment: yes i'm using react router but the app keeps refreshing when i navigate between pages, i've added the app component code if you could take a look a it thanks!