# React context not saving updates

Tags: reactjs, ionic4, react-context, react-functional-component

I created a react project for music/artists.

I'm using the React context for accessing artists data across components:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const ArtistContext = createContext(null);

const ArtistContextProvider = props => {
    const [artists, setArtists] = useState([]);

    const addArtist = new_artist => {
        setArtists([...artists, new_artist])
    };

    return (
        <ArtistContext.Provider value={{artists, addArtist}}>
            {props.children}
        </ArtistContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default ArtistContextProvider;
```

I can successfully get the data from the artist context object and also execute de addArtists methods, but the artist I pass to the function is not saved and the variable stills returns the default value.

My usage in a component:

```
const { artists, addArtist } = useContext(ArtistContext);

useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    api.get('artists?manager=1'))
    .then(function(response) {
        artist = response.data.items[0];
        addArtist(artist);
        window.location.href = '/artist/' + artist.id + '/tabs';
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

If i log inside the addArtist method, i can see that the artist object is valid, but then if i log again the artists array, it has the initial value.

I have tried different methods and syntax like class componenets with state, functional components with useState... So i'm guessing my syntax is correct but i'm missing some key concept about React.
Its my first project with React, so i'm probably missing something, but i can not figure it out even after reading the context documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your state/context object to localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies or server since accessing a different url path refreshes the page.

This link may help you store your state when you refresh the page.
[How to maintain state after a page refresh in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js)

Just encountered this today. Took me 2 days to resolve this lol