# Problem in persisting state with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm writing my first react-typescript application. Currently, I'm struggling with keeping state persistent on page refresh.

This my code to fetch user information and setStatus and setAuth.

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState(404)
const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    (
       async () => {
            try {
                  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/user`, {
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                  credentials: 'include',
                 });

                  const content = await response.json();
                  setStatus(content.status)
                  setAuth(true)
              }
              catch (error){
                  setAuth(false)
                  console.error(error)
              }
          }
      )();
}, [status, auth]);
```

After this, I'm redirecting the user depending on `auth` value.
if auth===true redirect to home page else to login page.

But whenever I refresh my page, states are set back to default.
i.e `status===404 and auth===false`

How do I keep my states persistent?

PS: I've tried `useEffect({...},[])` without `[status, auth]` as well. Getting the same result.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js?

Comment: Hi Tushar, that might help, but it uses local storage, and is it a good idea to use local storage for such trivial cheks?

Comment: Haha. This is not trivial. If you are reloading the page, think you are restarting the app, in a way. How will you have the previous value if you do not store it somewhere?

Comment: Hmm, that is a valid point. I'll try that solution then.