# useState value resets after navigating through NavLinks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a shopping cart app. On the checkout page, I can add and minus the quantity value of each item that is linked to the "itemCount" hook. But when I click on a navbar link to another page and come back, the item quantity is reset to 0. How can I get it so the current value remains even if I back out? Thanks.

**CartItem.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./CartItem.css";

const CartItem = (props) => {
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(0);
  const minusCartPrice = (counter) => {
    props.setCartTotal((counter -= props.price));
  };

  const addCartPrice = (counter) => {
    props.setCartTotal((counter += props.price));
  };
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <p>{props.name}</p>
      <p>
        <i
          className="bi bi-dash-square-fill minus-item"
          onClick={() => {
            props.setCartCount(props.minusItem);
            setItemCount(itemCount - 1);
            props.setCartTotal(minusCartPrice);
          }}
        ></i>
        {itemCount}

        <i
          className="bi bi-plus-square-fill add-item"
          onClick={() => {
            props.setCartCount(props.addItem);
            setItemCount(itemCount + 1);
            props.setCartTotal(addCartPrice);
          }}
        ></i>
      </p>

      <p>{props.price}</p>
      <p>Delete</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

**CartPage.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

import CartItem from "../CartItem/CartItem";
import "./CartPage.css";

const CartPage = (props) => {
  const minusItem = (counter) => {
    props.setCartCount((counter -= 1));
  };
  const addItem = (counter) => {
    props.setCartCount((counter += 1));
  };

  return (
    <div className="cart-page">
      <h3 className="cart-title">Shopping Cart</h3>
      <div className="cart-info">
        <div className="items-container">
          <div className="items-header">
            <h5>PRODUCT</h5>
            <h5>QUANTITY</h5>
            <h5>PRICE</h5>
          </div>
          {props.cartItems.map((item, id) => {
            return (
              <CartItem
                key={id}
                name={item.name}
                price={item.price}
                itemCount={item.count}
                setCartCount={props.setCartCount}
                minusItem={minusItem}
                addItem={addItem}
                setCartTotal={props.setCartTotal}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="order-summary">
          <h5>Order Summary</h5>
          <hr />
          <h6>Items</h6>
          <p>{props.cartCount}</p>
          <h6>Total Price</h6>
          <p>${props.cartTotal.toFixed(2)}</p>
          <button>Checkout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartPage;
```

Comment: What component is rendering `CartPage` and what does `setCartCount` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To keep your state during app's navigation, consider putting your state on a global state (Redux, Context) instead**

---

Or to keep them during browser page load, store them to browser storage like local storage or session storage.

**Something like this:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useCounter() {
  const initialState = () =>
    Number(window.localStorage.getItem("count") || null);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialState);

  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const decrement = () => setCount(count - 1);

  useEffect(() => window.localStorage.setItem("count", count), [count]);

  return { count, increment, decrement };
}

export default function Counter() {
  const { count, increment, decrement } = useCounter(5, 2);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="counter">{count}</div>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it does keep the current state. But if I have multiple items in the Cart Page, hitting increment or decrement on one does the same for the others as well. How do I keep the counter for each item separate from each other?

Comment: What is your cart object look like? You may instead store the whole object in local storage and then pick them up like a normal state object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data between page refresh, you might have to use localStorage.

- Store data to local storage when its changed.
- Retrieve data from local storage on page load.

For more information see: [How to maintain state after a page refresh in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28314368/8010366)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

- Store `itemCount` to global store (maybe using `Redux`/`Context` or any other state management)
- Store it in `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage or SessionStorage might be a simple solution.

You may simply use storages(local or session), or global scope state management library(such as Redux, Recoil).