# Keep multiple check boxes checked after refreshing the page in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I keep multiple checkboxes checked after refreshing the page using a function in React? I tried this and it's not working for me.

```
import { useEffect,useState } from "react";

const InputCheckBox = () => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(() => {
        const saved = localStorage.getItem("checked");
        const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved);
        return initialValue || "";
      });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(checked));
  }, [checked]);
return(
   <>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={(e) => {setChecked(e.target.checked)}
        />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: i think this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js) will help

Answer (score 0):

with localstorage... store there whatever you want and load it back whenever you generate the checkboxes