# How can I maintain the datagrid checkbox of the material ui in local storage?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, datagrid, refresh

I am facing one problem while using material ui.

```
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('row_selected', JSON.stringify(selectedRows));
  }, [selectedRows]);

// return
   <DataGrid
    components={{
      NoRowsOverlay: NoRows,
      Toolbar: GridToolbar,
    }}
    rows={tableData}
    columns={columns}
    checkboxSelection
    selectionModel={JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('row_selected'))}
    onSelectionModelChange={setSelectedRows}
    hideFooterPagination
  />
```

I'm using the checkbox function of datagrid, and even if I refresh the page, I'm saving it in local storage to maintain the checked.

However, the problem is that local storage is also reset because the new value is reset every refresh.

How can I keep it refreshed?

I saw this example [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314368/how-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-js), but I think it's different from the new value problem that automatically reset every refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code I've created ... I tested it and it works good

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGridPro } from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";

export default function DataGridProDemo() {
  const [selectionModelItems, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const parsedArrayFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage?.getItem("SelectedOption") || "[]");
    const mappedArray = parsedArrayFromLocalStorage.map(item => {
      return item;

    }, [selectionModelItems]);
    console.log("log", mappedArray);
    setSelectionModel(mappedArray);


  }, []);

  console.log("selectionModelItems from outsource is : ", selectionModelItems);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 520, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPro
        columns={[
          { field: 'default', width: 150 },
          { field: 'name', width: 150 },
          { field: 'stars', width: 150 },
        ]}
        rows={[
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'MUI',
            stars: 28000,
            default: 'Open source',
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'DataGridPro',
            stars: 15000,
            default: 'Enterprise',
          },
        ]}
        rowHeight={38}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          // ids is array of seleced rows
          console.log("ids is : ", ids);
          setSelectionModel(ids);
// i made this condtion because onSelectionModelChange called after each render of the component and without this conditon storage will be empty every refresh
          if (ids.length > 0) {
            localStorage.setItem("SelectedOption", JSON.stringify(ids));
          }
        }}
        selectionModel={selectionModelItems ? selectionModelItems : []}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some comments in your code to explain what they do?

Comment: this is a working method, which can be used on the MIT version of MUI datagrid.